# Does this have repeated operation have a name?

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology, nested-radicals

For some $k\in \mathbb{R}$ taking $\sqrt{\sqrt{\dotsb\sqrt{k}}}$ with $N$ radicals, then taking $N\to \infty$, will give $1$. Does this series of operations have a name?

Comment: Maybe there's a clue in the [tag:nested-radicals] tag?

Comment: Maybe "iterated square root"? I'm not sure that the specific operation of repeatedly taking a square root merits having a name. This is simply the limit of $k^r$ as $r$ approaches zero along the sequence $\frac{1}{2}, \; \frac{1}{4}, \; \frac{1}{8}, \ldots$

Comment: Why do I feel like this is similar to the limit  $\lim  \limits_{N \to \infty}k^\frac{1}{N}$

Comment: sorry @DaveL.Renfro I was looking at mathjax tutorials to type out my comment before I saw yours

Comment: In comparison to $k^{1/N}$, this nested radical could just as easily be denoted $k^{(1/2)^N}$, I suppose...